# Pages in a Composite Application can't be seen because of the black theme in #IBMNotes 9

Tags: java, xpages, composite-component, lotus-notes

I am doing a composite application in Notes 9. When I add a new page to the CA the navigation entries are black and the navigation text is black so the text cannot be seen.( see image)

Is there anyway to disable the Notes 9 theme in a composite application so I can see the navigation entries?

[image]

If I look in the Mail CA the text is white on black background which is what I want. I did not find any properties for changing the text color in the mail file CA

Comment: I don't believe it's possible. In the mail file they are using Notes Mail Navigator component which is added to one of Sidebars of CA.